# Need a help in understanding the estimation of the norm for a bounded linear operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, proof-explanation

The estimation of the norm is given in the following pictures:

[image]
[image]

But I did not understand why in the last line the author said " since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, $\|A\| \geq m$ ", why because $\epsilon$ was arbitrary this leads to that $\|A\| \geq m$ ?

Could anyone clarify this for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of a general property of real numbers:

> Suppose that $X, Y \in \mathbb{R}$ are such that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ we have
>
> $$X \ge Y - \varepsilon$$
>
> Then $X \ge Y$.

Indeed, suppose $X < Y$, and consider $\varepsilon = \frac12(Y - X) > 0$.

We have:

$$X \ge Y - \varepsilon = Y - \frac12(Y - X) = \frac12(X+Y)$$

Multiplying by $2$ yields:

$$2X \ge X + Y$$

Therefore $X \ge Y$, which is a contradiction with our assumption.

Now, to obtain your statement simply consider $X = \|A\|$ and $Y = m$. The statement that $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary just means that $\|A\| > m - \varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$.